# Single-Sign-On between web app and native app using ADAL

Tags: azure, authentication, single-sign-on, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory

We have a web application (Multi-Tenant) and a WPF application and we use [ADAL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-libraries/) to sign in to them. We want to have a single sign-on experience between these two. i.e. when user signs-in on the web app, then don't prompt them to sign-in on the WPF app and vice versa. And when the user signs off in one, sign them off on both sides. How could that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today there is no way to achieve that. The WPF app uses tokens, the web app uses session cookies. There is no shared context between the two and no standard mechanism to model it.

Comment: Is it possible to have a link from WPF app to open a browser session with user already logged-in?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier... No.

Comment: I was thinking maybe we could create a link on WPF app that include encrypted token as query string. Similar to those links in emails that log you directly into your account on a web site.

Comment: putting tokens in a querystring is definitely bad practice (they stay in the history), I would not recommend that. However it would not buy you anything: tokens must be used by the client that requested them, and in any case you would not be able to exchange that token for a cookie (which is really the artifact that represents a session in a browser based app)